# How to put Parse data in an array

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

I need to put data in the array using a query, but it only works in the block. I searched here and found out that it's because the findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock is asynchronous, but how can I make it synchronous then?

```
var cities = [String]()

func loadCityArray() {

    let citiesVisited = PFQuery(className: "Trips")
    citiesVisited.whereKey("userId", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId)!)

    citiesVisited.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if let objects = objects {
            for object in objects {
               let city = object["cityId"] as! String

                let query = PFQuery(className: "Cities")
                query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: city)
                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
                    if let objects = objects {
                        for object in objects {
                            self.cities.append(object["cityName"] as! String)
                        }
                   }
                })
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't make it synchronous. Do the things you want to do after the `for object in objects` loop in the block e.g. reload the table view (on the main thread).

Comment: the problema is that it's not a table view, I need this data outside the block to put in a geo chart!!

Comment: Then put it inside the block in the geo chart. What's the difference? It just happens later.

Comment: You mean call the func to make the geo chart inside the block?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's the usual way. Alternatively use a custom completion block to return the data asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to make that synchonous on the main thread. That is strongly discouraged.

You rather want to store the things you need from the request in instance variables and tell the corresponding View Controller new values are present in the block.

**edit**:

Suppose you have an object waiting to use the data:

```
var chart : DataConsumer?
```

In the block where you get the data,

```
chart.useData(data)
```

**edit 2**:

the `useData` function should keep track of changes in the data set and make use of the information that new data arrived. For example, by displaying it.

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand what to do. I have a geochart and I want to use the array's data in it